# Divide an integer evenly with a maximum

Tags: algorithm, math, integer-partition

I need an algorithm for the following:

- I'm given a specified target sum *n*, and a specified limit *m*. These are both positive integers.
- I want to find an integer partition of the target sum *n* that has as few summands as possible.
- Each summand must be less than or equal to the limit *m*.
- Within the above constraints, the summands should be as close together as possible; that is, I want *n* to be partitioned as evenly as possible.

So, for example, if the target sum is *n* = 80 and each summand must be at most *m* = 30, then I need at least three summands, and the most even partition is **26 + 27 + 27**.

How would I compute that?

Comment: Why not 26, 26, 28? Why is 27 an even integer? Why not 40 2's?

Comment: you need to split it into three numbers?

Comment: How about 30, 30, 20? Your requirements are incomplete, as you can see. And it's hard not to think this you're asking someone to do your homework for you...

Comment: 80=1+1+1+...+1 80 times

Comment: Flagged as unclear what you are asking...because your requirements are either inconsistent, incorrectly recorded, or your example is wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you get the size of the array with the following formula using integer division:

```
size = (variable + maximum - 1) / maximum
```

Next you fill the array with the following formulas:

```
extra = variable % size;
value = variable / size;
for each array value, set to value + 1 as long as there's extra; 
    value when the extra goes to zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a QnD Algorithm and Code...untested.

```
 double n=107;
    double max = 22;
    int d = (int) Math.ceil(n/max);
    int[] result = new int[d];
    int res=0, i=0,iter=0;
    while(res!=n){
        iter= (int) Math.ceil(n/d);
        while(iter+res>n) iter--;
        res+=iter;
        result[i] = iter;
        System.out.println("i: " + i + " iter: " + iter + " sum: " +res);
        i++;
    }
```